# Cant compile and run java code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Using InteliJ IDEA version 12.1.6 I wanted to run the example from the Horstmann's 'Core Java' book:

```
public class Welcome
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] greeting = new String[3];
        greeting[0] = "Welcome to Core Java";
        greeting[1] = "by Cay Horstmann";
        greeting[2] = "and Gary Cornell";

        for (String g : greeting)
        System.out.println(g);
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelliJ IDEA\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelliJ IDEA\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Welcome
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Welcome
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

At the same time when compiling and executing a file in the command line everything is working correctly. Excuse me for such a question, I just started learning Java. :)

Comment: Please check your source roots. Welcome class should be under directory marked as source(blue in Project View.)

Comment: Seagull, I manually moved the file created by using javac (when I run Build - Make Project I do not see that .class file was created) in the command prompt to the **src** folder, but it is not displayed in the  Project View I still get the errors.

Comment: Did you add src dir to project sources?

Comment: If you mean Project Structure - Project Settings - Modules - Sources tab, then yes.

Comment: I solved the problem by transferring file Welcome.java instead of Welcome.class to the src folder. Now everything works as it should. So all my .java files should be placed in the directory, added in the tab Sources?

Comment: Yes. Idea will compile source files (*.java) from source root, and run compiled *class files. (placed in out directory by default)

Comment: Hmm, strange. I copied the first example from the book in the SRC folder, compile and run it. All ok. Cleared SRC and OUT folders, copied the second example from the book. Again, I get the errors described above. What may be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sergey, it's look like you are working wrong with Idea. There is a step-by-step tutorial at [wiki](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_running_your_first_Java_application), that describes some basic concepts, about roots, run configurations, sdk-s and dependencies.
It will be good, if you look at it. (**Exploring the project structure** and **Building(Running) the project** especially)

IDE is a great helper to learn language, especially such intellegent one, as Idea, so, it will be a good start, to get familiar with it.

Basically, for a start, all your code(not compiled classes) must be under the source roots, and runConfiguration must specify application entry point (class with `static void main()` method).

You shouldn't think about class files, jar archives or command line tools, IDEA can do all this for you.

Better concentrate on learning, as I think!