# Java runtime error: "Could not initialize class FormPreviewFrame"

Tags: java

To get it out of the the way i'm a complete n00b and here i am learning java

ide : intellij

Problem: I imported the acm library to my project successfully but i get this error when I run a simple test program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class FormPreviewFrame
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at acm.util.JTFTools.readMainClassFromClassPath(JTFTools.java:1092)
    at acm.util.JTFTools.getMainClass(JTFTools.java:461)
    at acm.program.Program.main(Program.java:1320)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

**And here is my program:**

```
import acm.program.*;

public class hello extends ConsoleProgram{

   public void run(){
       println("Hello World");
   }

}
```

Really easy I know but I was just testing to see if it would work with intellij but it spit out an error.

Comment: Do you have a `main` method?

Comment: As eckes and you pointed out, the acm library doesn't need to include a main method and your issue is related to IntelliJ, maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241265/cant-compile-and-run-java-code-in-intellij-idea

Comment: It does not look like a good idea to use this library for java learning. At least not with an IDE. If you use the javac and java commands as described in the tutorial it might work better.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with IntelliJ, even less to do with the compiler, and less again to do with compiler-construction.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        new hello().start(args);
    }
```

The whole program will look like:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class hello extends ConsoleProgram{

   public void run(){
       println("Hello World");
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new hello().start(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a main method the library will search for the main class via various methods. The method on your case which fails is "readFromClassPath". This will open all JAR on the classpath and look for a Manifest with main-class entry. Looks like this is not compatible with the IDE.

As the tutorial does not describe this and you do not mention that you set it up correctly I think it just finds a wrong one.

If you keep the main() it should work (maybe not, I am unclear how the library works at all. It is certainly using non-standard methods all over the place). If the main method does not help, it seems to honor a system property like this: `-Djava.main=hello`

Comment: (I think you dont do yourself a favor with using this library)

Answer (score 0):

I hit this too.

I do not fully understand what's going on, but a solution is simple enough for Karel.

- Extract spl.jar (unzip it)
- Modify Karel.java.  You'll find a line that says `catch (Exception ex)` and does nothing.  Add another `catch` clause to catch `NoClassDefFoundError`.
- `javac Karel.java`
- `jar cf spl.jar *`

Do the same for `JTFTools`.  My `spl.jar` doesn't have the source, but you can find it at https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/.